# Google maps "'a' is not defined error"

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am getting that "'a' is not defined" error that a lot of people seem to be getting.

Some people point to the geocoder, but in this link there shouldn't be any geocoder lookup because its a straight to lat/lng/zoom. I've tried everything I can think of but just can't seem to get rid of the error.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

http://www.cyclistsroadmap.com/eng/map/35.682816642299926/139.68360900878906/13/
(Using API V3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

I was trying to remove a listener that wasn't set yet.